# Web API routing, two routes matches

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, attributerouting

I have the following two actions set up in my `ApiController`:

```
[POST("api/admin/image/{id}/upload")]
[Authorize(Roles = RoleNames.Administrator)]
public Foo UploadVersion(int id)

public Bar Post(int id, Baz x) {}
```

Given this route configuration, they are conflicting:

```
context.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "Admin_Api",
    routeTemplate: "api/admin/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new 
        {
             id = RouteParameter.Optional
        });
```

My guess is that `UploadVersion` also gets some sort of default route through the route mapping, but how can I prevent that?

In case anyone is wondering what I am trying to do:

```
POST /api/admin/image/{id}/upload -> UploadVersion()
POST /api/admin/image/{id}        -> Post()
```

Comment: Try route "api/admin/{controller}/{id}/{action}. In route defaults add action="DefaultAction". Add [ActinoName("DefaultAction")] for Post method. Details in http://blog.appliedis.com/2013/03/25/web-api-mixing-traditional-verb-based-routing/

Comment: I couldn't get this to work. No matter what I do with these two routes, they seem to collide. For now I have changed the `Post()` to `Put()`, so I can at least test the functionality.

Answer (score 1):

According to the routing you have set up, they are the same route and there is no way to distinguish from them. You will get this route every single time:

```
POST /api/admin/image/{id}        -> Post()
```

Try modifying your routes so they look like this:

```
POST /api/admin/image/upload/{id} -> UploadVersion()
POST /api/admin/image/{id}        -> Post()
```

Comment: I changed the `POST`-attribute to `[POST("api/admin/image/upload/{id}")]`. This still gives the same error (shortened to match example): Multiple actions were found that match the request: 
Foo UploadedVersion(Int32) on type ImageController
Bar Post(Int32, Baz) on type ImageController

Comment: Try modifying or removing the "api/admin/{controller}/{id}" route configuration altogether. I think it's getting hung up on that one. As in, it's trying to parse your "image" path as a controller, and the route is actually matching on your "api/admin/{controller}/{id}".

Comment: I tried this as well, couldn't get that to work. I've temporarily (maybe permanently?) changed the Post() to a Put() so I can get on with other work, but fixing this would be great.